# How to log request processing time in JAX-RS filter

Tags: jax-rs, quarkus

I have JAX-RS web app, and i want to log amount of time from getting request to response. It was easy in the Spring Boot with servlet filters. But the filter in my app does not work properly:

```
@Provider
public class RequestLogFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    private long requestStartTime;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        requestStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
        long requestFinishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(requestFinishTime - requestStartTime);
    }

}
```

It works fine in the first method, where current timestamps writes in the `requestStartTime`. But, seems like the second method has own copy of `requestStartTime` variable, because it the second method it always equals to zero. So i cant calculate the difference between variables. What can i do instead to log request processing time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are implementing both `ContainerRequestFilter` and `ContainerResponseFilter` in the same class, it seems that 2 different instances are created, therefore the variable `requestStartTime` is different between the 2 instances.

This problem was reported on the Eclipse Jersey project and considered a bug, which has been solved, see https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/3796.

Here the whole discussion: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxrs-api/issues/605.

The argument was that this behavior does not conform the JAX-RS specification (Section 4.1):

> By default a single instance of each provider class is instantiated
>   for each JAX-RS application

But Quarkus uses RESTEasy, so I guess that it doesn't contain that fix.

Anyway, even if a single instance was created (for example using the annotation `@Singleton`) you still shouldn't use an instance variable to keep the start time since concurrent requests would override it (thanks to @areus for pointing that out).

Instead you could save the start time on the properties of `ContainerRequestContext` on `ContainerRequestFilter.filter()` and then get it and use it on `ContainerResponseFilter.filter()`:

```
@Provider
public class RequestLogFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        long requestStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        requestContext.setProperty("requestStartTime", requestStartTime);
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
        long requestStartTime = (long) requestContext.getProperty("requestStartTime");
        long requestFinishTime = System.nanoTime();
        long duration = requestFinishTime - requestStartTime;
        System.out.println("duration: " + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(duration) + " ms");
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution 2 is the only valid. If there is only one instance concurrent requests would override `requestStartTime`

Answer (score 2):

Actually, something similar is built-in to Quarkus thanks to the MicroProfile Metrics API:

1. Add the SmallRye Metrics extension (quarkus-smallrye-metrics) to your pom.xml
2. This should be enabled by default, but feel free to explicitly enable the RestEasy/JAX-RS metrics to be registered by adding the following to application.properties:

   > quarkus.smallrye-metrics.extensions.enabled=true

The metrics (# invocations, time spent in each) will be added to the /metrics endpoint. The metrics will show up once you invoke the endpoint.