# Log incoming time of request in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I would like the log to mention something whenever an incoming request reaches the server, so that I can see its exact time of entry.

Rationale is that I would like to see and follow in the log what happens to the request, from its incoming time up to the response time, so that I can see where the time is spent, in order to take decisions relating to optimisation.

This is on a local server used only for such debug activity, so there would be only one request at a time.

Here is an example (partial) log from the moment a request comes.

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_."id" as id1_6_
    from
        "User" user0_ 
    where
        (…)
2021-12-20 01:35:43,545 TRACE [org.hib.typ.des.sql.BasicBinder] (executor-thread-192) binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - (…)
Hibernate: 
    select
    (…)
2021-12-20 01:35:43,735 TRACE [org.hib.typ.des.sql.BasicBinder] (executor-thread-192) binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [2]
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_."id" as id1_6_0_,
        (…)
2021-12-20 01:35:44,275 TRACE [org.hib.typ.des.sql.BasicBinder] (executor-thread-192) binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - (…)
2021-12-20 01:35:44,655 INFO  [io.git.oli.die.UserService] (executor-thread-192) Got user encoded io.github.oliviercailloux.diet.dao.Base64@4ca04a5c.
2021-12-20 01:35:44,656 INFO  [io.git.oli.die.UserService] (executor-thread-192) Got user encoded io.github.oliviercailloux.diet.dao.Base64@4ca04a5c, with events size 0.
2021-12-20 01:35:44,656 INFO  [io.git.oli.die.VideoService] (executor-thread-192) Querying for videos.
(…)
```

I would like to have a supplementary entry that indicates the incoming time (something like `2021-12-20 01:35:43,232 TRACE [org.some-quarkus-class] (executor-thread-192) incoming request`), so that I can compute the time taken by each step compared to the starting time. Currently, the intermediate time stamps are visible, but not the incoming time stamp.

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61620936/how-to-log-request-processing-time-in-jax-rs-filter) and [this bug report](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/13129) (or [this issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/8656)); and probably I could plug into the [HttpAuthenticationMechanism Customization](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-customization#httpauthenticationmechanism-customization) mechanism, but these provide only indirect solutions or workarounds. I hope that some simple solution exists, like a simple configuration entry, that allows to log an entry at the start of the request.

Here is the relevant part of my current `application.properties`.

```
quarkus.http.auth.basic=true
quarkus.http.auth.proactive=false
quarkus.security.jaxrs.deny-unannotated-endpoints=true

quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true
quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.bind-parameters=true
quarkus.log.min-level=TRACE
quarkus.log.category."org.apache.http".level=DEBUG
quarkus.http.access-log.enabled=true
quarkus.http.record-request-start-time=true
quarkus.http.access-log.pattern=%{REMOTE_HOST} %l %{REMOTE_USER} %{DATE_TIME} "%{REQUEST_LINE}" %{RESPONSE_CODE} %b %{RESPONSE_TIME} %T
```